# Do XMPP users need to be in same group to be able to communicate with each other?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using "openfire" XMPP server. I have setup the server and created two users

with name testUser1, testUser2.

they can send messages with each other when there are in the same group and cannot when there are not in group

Note: 
I do not want to create groups at all to avoid broadcasting of "Presence" stanza when one of the users come online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do XMPP users need to be in same group to be able to communicate with
>   each other?

**In general: No.** XMPP does not impose such a restriction for exchanging messages between entities. But of course, your server could impose one.

Comment: I have another question do the users need to be any group after all ?

Comment: No, they do not need to be in any group.

Comment: Thanks Flow, May be I am missing some settings in open fire :(

Answer (score 0):

There's no such restriction in XMPP. But you have to put full jid like user@server.if you use only user id it won't work.